# How to prove that if $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_n\:$ converges then $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_na_{2n}\:$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

How to prove that if $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_n\:$ converges then $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_na_{2n}\:$ converges?

Note: $a_n \in \mathbb R$

I tried to prove it using cauchy criterion
The idea was to use the partial sums.

let $\epsilon$>0

There exists $N_1$ such that for any $n>N_1$ and $p\ge1$

$$\left|\sum \:\:\:\:_{k=n+1}^{n+p}a_k\:\right|<\epsilon \:$$
There exists $N_2$ such that for any $n>N_2$ and $p\ge1$

$$\left|\sum \:\:\:\:_{k=n+1}^{n+p}a_{2k}\:\right|<\epsilon \:$$
We will take $N=max\left\{N_1,N_2\right\}$ and then for any $n>N$ and $p\ge1$:

$$\left|\sum \:\:_{k=n+1}^{n+p}a_ka_{2k}\:\right|\le \left|\sum \:\:\:_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\left(max\left\{a_k,a_{2k}\right\}\right)^2\:\right|\le ...<\epsilon $$

But I didn't manage to show the part with the three dots. Maybe it's not the way to prove this. Can I get help please ?

Comment: @zyx can you expand on that?

Comment: The answers have already disposed of the question, so I did not pursue it.  @madmatician

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be a problem. Let $\gamma=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ be a non-trivial cube root of $1$.
$$a_n= \frac{\gamma^n}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Then $\sum_n a_n$ converges but 
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} a_n a_{2n} = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\gamma^{3n}}{\sqrt{2}n}= \sum_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}n}=+\infty $$

For the real case set $b_n={\rm Re\;} a_n$ then $\sum_n b_n$ converge. However,
$${\rm Re} (\gamma^n) {\rm Re} (\gamma^{2n})=
 ){\rm Re} (\gamma^n) {\rm Re} (\gamma^{-n}) =({\rm Re} (\gamma^n))^2 \geq 1/4$$
so $\sum_n b_n b_{2n}\geq \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} \sum_n \frac{1}{n}=+\infty$.

Comment: Note that it's true via Dirichlet test when $a_{2n}$ is decreasing (and real).

Comment: Nicely done! What if the requirement was $a_n \in \mathbb R$? (I have been thinking about a counterexample but failed at finding one)

Comment: @madmatician The statement in my question  is true. It was at my final exam yesterday.
$a_n \in \mathbb R$

Comment: For a real example, take $a_n = \sin(2 n \pi/3)/\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

As H.H. Rugh's answer points out, the result doesn't hold in general. Here is a proof for the case $a_n>0$:

First note that $a_na_{2n}\leq \frac{a_n^2+a_{2n}^2}{2}$ for all $n$, and $0<a_n^2<a_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$ since $a_n\to 0$, hence
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_na_{2n}\leq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n}^2\ll \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n}\ll \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n<\infty$$

Comment: No need for $a_n>0$. Just absolute convergence will do

Comment: Sure, that works too.

Comment: @carmichael561 How can the statement be a false statement ?
I had it at my exam yesterday. We dont know if $a_n$ is positive for all $n$

Comment: It is not unheard of for exams to contain mistakes.

Comment: Also note that since $a_n\to 0,$ $|a_na_{2n}| \le |a_n|$ for large $n.$

Comment: There's a tiny typo. The correct is: $0<a^2_n<a_n$.

Comment: @Babak: Thanks, I'll fix it.

Comment: I forgot to add $\frac{1}{2}$ is omitted in the middle of the chain.

Comment: @idandi Are you positively sure that it didn't say `converges *absolutely*`?

Comment: @Babak: The $\ll$ symbol hides all the constants. Indeed, the constant might be something other than $\frac{1}{2}$ since we only have $0<a_n<1$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: @dxiv . I looked again . it says prove or disprove.
if it's coverge absolutely this statement is true ?

Comment: I'm not talking about the hidden constants. I'm saying this is not logically correct: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n}\ll\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$, since the LHS is larger.

Comment: @Babak: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ since the $a_n$ are non-negative, so the LHS is at most twice the RHS.

Comment: @idandi yes it is (see zhw.'s comment, use comparison test). In my opinion, your professor is mean. This is not the kind of exercise that should be put on a test

Comment: @madmatician all the question is in this form.

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes . my mistake

Comment: I think I didn't conveyed it well. Simply put, you've written $A+B\ll A$. This is not correct since the the LHS is greater that the RHS. Did you get my point?

Comment: @Babak: If $B\leq A$, then $A+B\leq 2A$, so $\ll $ is true with the implied constant being $2$. Do you get my point?

Comment: Oh! now, I get it. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Define

$$
a_{3k}=0, a_{3k+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3k+1}}, a_{3k+2}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3k+2}}
$$
then $\sum a_{n}$ converges but not $\sum a_{n}a_{2n}$.